# React Spring Boot Many to Many relationship CRUD

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make React + Spring Boot application. I have this `Book` entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Book {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="book_sequence",
            sequenceName = "book_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "book_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authoredBooks", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Author> authors;
    private Integer pageCount;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "publisher_id", nullable = false)
    private Publisher publisher;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    private Category category;
    private String isbn;

//constructors, setters and getters
}
```

It has many to many relationship. Owner of the relationship is `Author`entity:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Author {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="author_sequence",
            sequenceName = "author_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "author_sequence"
    )
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "book_author",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"))
    private List<Book> authoredBooks;
//constructors, setters and getters
}
```

For React side I have this `Book` type defined:

```
export type Book =  {
    authors: Author[],
    title: string,
    pageCount: number,
    publisher: Publisher,
    category: Category,
    isbn: string,

}

export type Author = {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
}
export type Category = {
    name: string
}
export type Publisher = {
    name: string;
}
```

Then I'm sending some data from frontend via form to api endpoint:

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormFields> = async (data: FormFields) => {

        const authors: Author[] = data.authors.map((author: string) => {
            const [firstName, lastName] = author.split(" ");
            return {
                firstName,
                lastName
            }
        });
        const newBook: Book = {
            title: data.bookTitle,
            pageCount: parseInt(data.pageCount),
            publisher: {
                name: data.publisher
            },
            category: {
                name: data.category
            },
            isbn: data.isbn,
            authors: authors,
        };
        await fetch("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/books/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newBook),
        });

    };
```

Object in frontend looks something like this:

```
{"title":"Example book","pageCount":300,"publisher":{"name":"Example publisher"},"category":{"name":"Example category"},"isbn":"Example ISBN","authors":[{"firstName":"Example","lastName":"Author"}]}
```

Controller receives data correctly and saves `Book` to database. However both `Author` and `Book` have their many to many field empty. How do I make CRUD in a good way so Book will have authors from backend saved?

This is how controller endpoint looks like:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public void addBook(@RequestBody Book book){
        bookService.addBook(book);
    }
```

BookService:

```
public void addBook(Book book){
        bookRepository.save(book);
    }
```

When i try to fetch saved book from database it has authors field empty:

```
{
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Example book",
        "authors": [],
        "pageCount": 300,
        "publisher": {
            "id": 152,
            "name": "Example publisher"
        },
        "category": {
            "id": 152,
            "name": "Example category"
        },
        "isbn": "Example ISBN"
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.